# How to get apps review and ratings from itunes connect

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, app-store-connect

Hello i am wondering if there is any way to get the app information like number of downloads, rating, review etc . from appstore or from itunes connect. If I call this url    http://itunes.apple.com/US/lookup?bundleId=com.XXX.XXX   it gives the some of the information related to that app like supported os, devices, images, etc. I would like to know do we have such permissions or such possibility to do that.

Any reference, link, or suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: www.appannie.com/
It will gives total number of downloads, reviews etc..

Comment: @vishnu thanks for the suggestion but i am looking for the developer support not the app which meets my requirement. i have to add this feature to my app.

Comment: If you have itunes-connect account for an app you can get download information from itunes by simulating http request /response but not without credentials. For ratings and reviews you can easily scrap them from itunes app-info pages.

Answer (score 19):

---

***Edit***

I found a new way by looking at what Apple does in iTunes Connect

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/apps/1076274943/platforms/ios/reviews?sort=REVIEW_SORT_ORDER_MOST_RECENT

---

***First answer***

Yes there is : https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=APP_ID/sortBy=mostRecent/json?l=fr

Where APP_ID is the ID of you app composed of numbers [0-9]+.

For exemple : https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=284882215/sortBy=mostRecent/json

---

Comment: Is that what you expected ?

Comment: Is there any way to view ALL reviews from EVERYWHERE?

Comment: @durazno did you get the solution regarding all reviews from everywhere.?

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. Where do we access this info from iTunes Connect? I know I saw it once but can't find it now.

Comment: This doesn't give all reviews, is there a way to get all the reviews?

Answer (score 2):

In case you're looking for an out-of-the-box API to handle reviews and ratings you should check ours (Appfigures) out:

- Read/Reply to Reviews: https://docs.appfigures.com/api/reference/v2/reviews

The following request will get you all of the reviews for Super Mario Run for iPhone in the US (but you can add any country or app):

`https://api.appfigures.com/reviews?countries=us&products=265018212233`

- Get ratings by country + over time: https://docs.appfigures.com/api/reference/v2/reports-ratings

This request will get you the current ratings for Super Mario Run in all countries:

`https://api.appfigures.com/v2/reports/ratings?products=265018212233&group_by=country`

Comment: These URL's no longer work unless you're already paying for the AppFigures Grow plan, which starts at $375 a month. The first returns a 404, the second you need to be authorised and best I can tell needs that plan.

From the docs linked here https://docs.appfigures.com/api/reference/v2/reports-ratings :

"The Public Data API add-on is required to access data for products that are not owned by your account. Free accounts must use the Public Data API, even for products that are in their account."

The Public Data API can only be enabled on Grow accounts.